# How to add raw XML text to SOAPBody element

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML text that is generated by the application, and I need to wrap a SOAP envelope around it and later make the web service call.

The following code builds up the envelope, but I don't know how the add the existing XML data into the `SOAPBody` element.

```
    String rawXml = "<some-data><some-data-item>1</some-data-item></some-data>";

    // Start the API
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope env = part.getEnvelope();

    // Get the body. How do I add the raw xml directly into the body?
    SOAPBody body = env.getBody();
```

I have tried `body.addTextNode()` but it adds content so `<` and others get escaped.

Comment: what about `body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rawXml));`? I didn't try this, but in documentation I saw that `SOAPBody` inherits from DOM Element, so it's possible to work ;)
`document` is a DOM Document object.

Comment: @rzysia That was close. I got an WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR exception when doing it, but then `body.addDocument(document);` did the trick =). I'll post full code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following adds the XML as a Document:

```
Document document = convertStringToDocument(rawXml);
body.addDocument(document);
```

Document creation:

```
private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I took the `convertStringToDocument()` logic from [this post](http://www.journaldev.com/1237/java-convert-string-to-xml-document-and-xml-document-to-string).

Comment: If you have exception - `Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR` you can solve it by set  `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Comment: These name spaces should be added:import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;import java.io.StringReader;

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell the XML Serializer to not to parse and escape the `SOAPBody` content as XML. You can do that by enclosing the XML inside `<![CDATA[]]>`

```
    String rawXml = "<![CDATA[<some-data><some-data-item>1</some-data-item></some-data>]]>";

    // Start the API
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage request = mf.createMessage();
    SOAPPart part = request.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope env = part.getEnvelope();

    // Get the body. How do I add the raw xml directly into the body?
    SOAPBody body = env.getBody();

    SOAPElement se = body.addTextNode(rawXml);

    System.out.println(body.getTextContent());
```

**EDIT**

```
<some-data><some-data-item>1</some-data-item></some-data>
```

This is the output of

```
System.out.println(body.getTextContent());
```

Comment: It solved the character escaping, but the `<![CDATA[]]>` is also added by the serializer. I am not sure it will be safely interpreted by the our customer server.

Comment: It will be ignored when the data is retrieved as Text Content. After that the customer server have to parse it to read it as XML.